# Rotating camera lookAt point with quarternions

Tags: opengl, geometry, glm-math

I am trying to rotate the camera using quarternions but i have problems doing it.

The first thing that I notices now is that when I execute this the Camera  Position and Camera LookAt become  almost the same and in some cases they are the same and then i get precision problems and all other problems relating to it when i try and move the camera.

```
if (Input::getInstance()->isMouseDown(SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT-1)){
        //log_.debug("Camera Mouse Left down");
        glm::vec2 mouseDelta = glm::ivec2(oldX, oldY) - Input::getInstance()->getMousePosition();
        glm::quat q1 = glm::quat(glm::vec3(glm::radians(mouseDelta.y), glm::radians(mouseDelta.x), 0.0f));
        cameraLook_ = q1 * (direction * mouseSensitivity_) * glm::conjugate(q1) + cameraPosition_;
        //cameraLook_ = glm::rotate(cameraLook_, mouseDelta.x  * delta, glm::vec3(0,1,0));
        //cameraLook_ = glm::rotate(cameraLook_, mouseDelta.y  * delta, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched back to matrices for my solution, because for me they are easier to work with at the moment.

There are few things i need to understand about quarternions then I can fix my old problem.

```
    glm::mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::translate(cameraPosition_ - glm::vec3(1.0));
    rotationMatrix *= glm::rotate(mouseDelta.x, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    rotationMatrix *= glm::rotate(mouseDelta.y, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    rotationMatrix *= glm::translate(-cameraPosition_ + glm::vec3(1.0));
    cameraLook_ = glm::vec3(rotationMatrix * glm::vec4(cameraLook_, 1.0f));
```